# Maven build getting failed because unexpected error

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-16.04, wagon

I have simple project HelloWorld with only single dependency of junit.
I am trying to compile sudo mvn clean install and it shows build faild with following logs,

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testMyConfig 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurityManager.java:65)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(java.base@9-ea/Cipher.java:2595)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(java.base@9-ea/Cipher.java:2619)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:602)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:574)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:460)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:1074)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuiteList(java.base@9-ea/SSLContextImpl.java:353)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(java.base@9-ea/SSLContextImpl.java:41)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/SSLContextImpl.java:582)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-ea/Class.java:291)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(java.base@9-ea/Provider.java:1844)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/Provider.java:1820)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-ea/GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-ea/GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(java.base@9-ea/SSLContext.java:166)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(java.base@9-ea/SSLContext.java:98)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(java.base@9-ea/SSLSocketFactory.java:123)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(java.base@9-ea/HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.createConnManager(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.<clinit>(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:269)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/Constructor.java:455)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.connector.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.lookupWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.<init>(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:535)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:91)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(java.base@9-ea/UnixPath.java:75)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(java.base@9-ea/UnixPath.java:69)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(java.base@9-ea/UnixFileSystem.java:280)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(java.base@9-ea/Paths.java:84)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:254)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:49)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:82)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:79)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:78)
    ... 95 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.177 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-11T16:59:14+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/26M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.2.1.jar
constituent[1]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-artifact-3.2.1.jar
constituent[2]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.19.jar
constituent[3]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
constituent[4]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
constituent[5]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
constituent[6]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.2.1.jar
constituent[7]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/wagon-http-2.6-shaded.jar
constituent[8]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
constituent[9]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
constituent[10]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar
constituent[11]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/sisu-guice-3.1.3-no_aop.jar
constituent[12]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.2.1.jar
constituent[13]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-compat-3.2.1.jar
constituent[14]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[15]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.2.1.jar
constituent[16]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-embedder-3.2.1.jar
constituent[17]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/aether-connector-wagon-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[18]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[19]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-settings-3.2.1.jar
constituent[20]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.6.jar
constituent[21]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.2.1.jar
constituent[22]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[23]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
constituent[24]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.17.jar
constituent[25]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.2.1.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/wagon-file-2.6.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/wagon-http-shared-2.6.jar
constituent[29]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/aether-impl-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[30]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.2.1.jar
constituent[31]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
constituent[34]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.0.0.M5.jar
constituent[35]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/aether-api-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/aether-spi-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/share/maven3/conf/logging/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurityManager.java:65)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(java.base@9-ea/Cipher.java:2595)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(java.base@9-ea/Cipher.java:2619)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:602)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:574)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:460)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/CipherSuite.java:1074)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuiteList(java.base@9-ea/SSLContextImpl.java:353)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(java.base@9-ea/SSLContextImpl.java:41)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/SSLContextImpl.java:582)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-ea/Class.java:291)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(java.base@9-ea/Provider.java:1844)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/Provider.java:1820)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-ea/GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-ea/GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(java.base@9-ea/SSLContext.java:166)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(java.base@9-ea/SSLContext.java:98)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(java.base@9-ea/SSLSocketFactory.java:123)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(java.base@9-ea/HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.createConnManager(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.<clinit>(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:269)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.base@9-ea/Constructor.java:455)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.connector.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.lookupWagon(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.<init>(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:535)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:91)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(java.base@9-ea/UnixPath.java:75)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(java.base@9-ea/UnixPath.java:69)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(java.base@9-ea/UnixFileSystem.java:280)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(java.base@9-ea/Paths.java:84)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:254)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:49)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:82)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:79)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-ea/JceSecurity.java:78)
    ... 95 more
```

I have tried doing lots things but its not getting off.
I am using ubuntu 16.04LTS.
My java version is 1.7.0.80 and maven version is 3.2.1.
Need serious suggestions.

Comment: Please check your jars whether you have added all the dependent jars in it.

Comment: Can you explain it little more?

Comment: which version  do you use for org.apache.httpcomponents?

Comment: All these modules are present under ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents, 

httpasyncclient  httpclient  httpcomponents-asyncclient  httpcomponents-client httpcomponents-core  httpcore  httpcore-nio  httpmime  project.

All with different versions.

Comment: at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(java.base@9-ea/UnixPath.java:75) - This line indicates its something to do with paths. Do all folders have the right permissions?

Comment: Its clean. No problem with any access. All are open.

Comment: I am running build with sudo so I don't thinks it has anything to do with folder  permissions. Still give me your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 2):

Updating to Apache Maven 3.6.0 solved it for me. Had to uninstall the package and install it from tar.gz, Ubuntu does not have the latest version.
The question is still valid for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS :)